# How to save output to console and file simultaneously in RStudio server?

Tags: r, logging, console, rstudio, rstudio-server

I want to see the outputs of my calculations in the console, but simultaneously save it to a file. The `sink()` function is not suitable for me, since it simply redirects the output to a file, while I need to write them both -- in the console and in the file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `sink` has an argument `split` which will send the output both to file and to the output stream (console). e.g.,

```
> sink(file="test.file", split = TRUE)
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
> sink()
> x <- read.csv("test.file")
> x
    Sepal.Length.Sepal.Width.Petal.Length.Petal.Width.Species
1 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
>
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked it on my code and this is what I wanted